# Deploying Elasticsearch on Ubuntu Server

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to deploy my own instance of elasticsearch on DigitalOcean on an ubuntu server. However I am struggling to get the server pointing to the right place. This is my first time trying to deploy anything myself.

Running:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

Gives me the expected GET request:

```
{
  "name" : "Test_Node_1",
  "cluster_name" : "TEST_Cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "RWPkFQ37SAe-687L-iLV9Q",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.0.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "b7e28a7",
    "build_date" : "2019-04-05T22:55:32.697037Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.7.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
 }
```

However when I go to the `elasticsearch.yml` file and change the `network.hosts` to point to my server IP, it does not work and gives me this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <server-ip> port 9200: Connection refused
```

Any advice on how to get it working? Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: What you can see on your ES logs?

Comment: @Rohlik Where can I find the logs?

Comment: Try look at /var/log/elasticsearch/ dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have to edit the /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and change the network.hosts variable to 0.0.0.0

this is a solution, but it's probably not the best solution.

I highly recommend AWS's open distro

[Open Distro for Elasticsearch](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/install/deb/)

Comment: Okay, I'll give this a try. Would you be able t explain why this works so I have a better grasp of it?

Comment: allows input from any ip on the machine, localhost, 127.0.0.1, or the public IP. This will aid in debugging as it will let you know whether or not the IP you are providing is wrong. Otherwise it might be best to restart your deployment and try with the opendistro version. I had no issues setting that up on an ubuntu server

Comment: I'm just going to reset my droplet and try this. So once I change the yml file I should be able to access the port 9200 by going http://<server-ip>:9200?

Comment: yep exactly, if it works for you please select the answer

Comment: In the setup link you gave me, there are the 3 curl commands. To test if it works on my server ip can just do 'curl -XGET https://<server-ip>:9200/_cat/plugins?v -u admin:admin --insecure'? The localhost version works so I'm one step closer!

Comment: I still cannot get this to work. The server just won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

Please check after restarting the Es.

```
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
```